# Find multivariable limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to find the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}}\text{.}$$

I tried the following approach

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}}&=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{\frac{x^4y^4}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}}\text{,}\\
\end{align*}$$

now I just need to find
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^4y^4}{x^2y^2+(x-y^2)}&=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{1+\frac{(x-y)^2}{x^2y^2}}\\
\end{align*}$$

and that's where I got lost. I have no idea how to work with

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(x-y)^2}{x^2y^2}\text{.}$$

Expanding the numerator didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Note that if $xy\not=0$ (otherwise the ratio is zero), then
$$0\leq \frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}}\leq \frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2y^2}}=|xy|.$$

Comment: Thank you! Now it's clear.

Comment: The cases $x=0,y=0$  might be worth a mention

Answer (score 0):

By polar coordinates we have

$$\frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}}=r^3\frac{\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta+(\cos \theta -\sin\theta)^2}}\to 0$$

indeed

$$\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta+(\cos \theta -\sin\theta)^2\ge m>0$$